# issue with PushNotification Integration in iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, push-notification

i created one provisional profile long back and for that profile now i enabled push notification and i downloaded that modified provisional profile included that in project.

and i wrote "[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];" in app delegate to register my device for notifications.

once i run the app in device, i am getting the error like "Fail to register for remote notifications: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x5ae3f0 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}"

and i am not understanding where i did mistake.

can any one give me the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This error says that no apns is enabled in that provisional , so just revoke the existing apns development or production and redo it , then modify the provisional profile. Then you will not get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure each and every step you have done properly like:

Step 1: Make Request Certificate from your system key Chain access.

Step 2: Upload this certificate on your developer account.

Step 3: Enable Push Notification services or your Application on developer account.

Step 4: Download p12 and provisioning profile and set both on your system key chain access just double click on both.

Step 5: Make sure you use Proper bundle identifier.

Step 6: Select  proper code signing identity.

If you done these all above steps then push notification defenatly should be work.